# <small> in <h2> in <header> OR <small> next to <h2> in <header>?

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a ***description*** by using `<small>` tag,

and I also have a ***large title*** with `<h2>` tag, and they are all **inside** a `<header>` tag,

this is what it looks like now:

```
<header>
    <h2>User settings</h2>
    <small>Yep, here's the settings for you.</small>
</header>
```

But I'm not sure if the following usage would be better to make those tags meaningful?

```
<header>
    <h2>
        User settings
        <small>Yep, here's the settings for you.</small>
    </h2>
</header>
```

Should I put `<small>` in `<h2>` instead of putting `<small>` in `<header>`?

Answer (score 2):

well, it depends

if you put your `<small>` tag inside `<h2>` it will be more important (note that using `<small>` also affects importance)

on the other hand, some tools like *html outliners* will also list `<small>` content, which might not be desired behaviour

Answer (score 2):

These options are not semantically equivalent. Putting `small` inside `h2` means that the whole content of `h2`, including `small` content, is the heading that identifies the current section (or the whole page). For example, screen readers may read this whole long text as a document navigation option. With `small` outside `h2`, the section (or page) is identified with the short text that is the content of `h2` element only.

Also, I doubt that [the `small` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-small-element) is the right choice for such sub-description. Wouldn't just `p` element (as [suggested](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines) in W3C HTML spec for sub-headings) be more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla says: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

```
<header>
<hx></hx>
</header>
```

prefer `<small>` in `<hx>`

twitter bootstrap docs prefer small in hx
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-headings

Comment: can you cite which part of this article? because I see no connection

Comment: there is no strict rule for small tag

Comment: so why did you say that `small` is preferred to be inside `hx`?

Comment: also if you use small outside of h2, you should change hx's display property to inline

Comment: MDN doesn't suggest `small` inside `hx`, on the contrary, their example with `img` outside `h1` seems to imply their preference for the '`small` outside `h2`' option. Changing `display` property has nothing to do with elements themselves, it's just the matter of desired presentation (I supposed that OP wants two lines of text, like title with subtitle). Bootstrap is focused on presentation, not semantics, so its choices aren't necessarily semantically best.